# What does "most" and "least" significant dimension mean?

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I am reading a book on C++ AMP and don't really understand some of the terminology:

> Always choose your tile size so that the number of threads in the
>   least significant dimension is at least 16, and use 32 or even 64 if
>   you can.

I had seen similar terminology used in the Eigen documentation, so I suspect this is quite common usage.

So let's suppose I have a 2D index, array, whatever:

```
// construct it:
ArrayType my2DArray(rows,columns);

// now index it:
float element = my2DArray[rowIdx,colIdx];
```

Forgetting for a moment the *type* of `ArrayType`, and thinking more about the terminology, which would be the *most* and *least* significant dimension of that array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When allocating threads logically in multiple dimensions, there is generally a mapping from that N-dimensional space to a linear space.  The dimension that varies the linear space least is the least significant dimension.

As an example, mapping a 2-dimensional (X,Y) coordinate to linear space might be determined using the expression (Y * width + X).  Here, X is the least significant dimension and Y is the most significant dimension.  Likewise, for a 3-dimensional (X,Y,Z) space, the expression might be (Z * width * height + Y * width + X).  Here, X is still the least significant, but Z is the most significant.  Your layout may not necessarily be the same, for example you may choose to map linear space to (Z * width * height + X * height + Y), in which case Y is the least significant dimension.